# Retrieve Joomla 2.5 component item id

Tags: joomla

I am developing a component,i want to retrieve the items id and use that id, so that everytime the page load that item id will be used in other things.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve the ID of your components item you will need to do several things:

Create the link to the item using it's ID e.g.

```
$mylink = 'index.php?option=com_yourcomponent&view=myitemview&id=99'
```

You should then pass that link through `JRoute` incase the user has SEF enabled:

```
$myRoutedLink = JRoute::_($myLink);
```

This ensures that when you try and access the ID when building your items page it's available. For Joomla! 2.5 you should use [JInput](http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput) to retrieve variables as [JRequest](http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_and_Filtering_GET_and_POST_requests_with_JRequest%3a%3agetVar) has been depreciated and replaced since J1.7.

The first step is to get the Joomla! instance and then the input object before retrieving your variables e.g.

```
// Get Joomla! instance
$jAp = JFactory::getApplication();
$jInput = $jAp->input;
```

Now we can get your variables:

```
// Get variables
$passedID = $jInput->get('id',0) // Where the 0 is the default if 'ID' doesn't exist.
$passedInt = $jInput->getInt('myInt',0) // You can also get JInput to give the right type back
```

Answer (score 0):

i know about joomla 1.5.xx

and i have used to get the itemid from the url is:

```
$itemid = JRequest::getVar('itemid');
```

hope this will help you also. Follow the link for more info [JRequest](http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_data_from_GET_and_POST_requests)

Comment: Thanks All,  $id=JRequest::getInt('id'); is working in Joomla 2.5